# Structure of Males and Females

Tags: c++, structure

l should  use array a[10] whose elements are type struct osoba to type in 10 names and sex of  persons  whos nameas are those...then l should use  function void brosoba to determine how many of males and females is there (how many i typed in) my only problem here is  how to call that function t ostart working since   proffesor insisted on using pointers in void function while working with array... :(

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct osoba 
{
    char naziv[30];
    char pol[30];
}a[10];

 void brosoba(osoba *x[])
 {


    int Zene=0,Muskarci=0;

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {

        if(*x[i]-> pol=='z')Zene++;
        if(*x[i]->pol=='m')Muskarci++;

    }
    printf("Muskaraca ima:%d\n Zena ima:%d\n",Muskarci,Zene);

 }

 int main()
 {
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("Unesi ime osobe %d\n",i);
        gets(a[i].naziv);

        while(getchar()!='\n');

        printf("Unesi pol osobe %d(m/z)\n",i);
        gets(a[i].pol);
        while(getchar()!='\n');
    }
      brosoba();
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: It should be noted that some people are not male nor female. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermaphrodite

Comment: @EdHeal then lets assume that some are aliens,dead,changed sex etc...l just want to keep it simple MALE or FEMALE but stil l cant call the function to count them :(

Comment: @user3127589 to get back on track what you want it `brosoba((osoba **)&a);` in c++. This looks a lot more like C than it looks like C++, so I should mention that you can avoid the cast in C.

Comment: @EdHeal :D they are but still peaple are not problem here

Comment: @PeterT thanx mate  thats what l was looking for...now l see that my function is wrong too  but still ill somehow manage to fix it :D

Comment: @user3127589 it looks like your function expects a "array of pointer of osoba" but you now provide it with "pointer to array of osoba". Also `*x[i]->` is redundant, either do `x[i]->` or `*x[i].` not both

Comment: @PeterT didn't  delete * while was typing entering code to website...i use x[i]-> not *x[i]-> but it tells  that its forbidden to compare pointer and integer so I'm stuck again

Answer (score 4):

Here's my take on this in standard C++, instead of C

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

enum class gender_t { male, female, other };

struct osoba
{
    std::string name;
    gender_t gender;
};

static inline gender_t to_gender(char input)
{
    switch(input)
    {
        case 'm': case 'M': return gender_t::male;
        case 'f': case 'F': return gender_t::female;
        case 'o': case 'O': case '*': case '?': return gender_t::other;
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("Unknown gender specification");
}

void brosoba(std::vector<osoba> x)
{
    auto pred = [](gender_t g, osoba const& o) { return g == o.gender; };

    using namespace std::placeholders;
    std::cout << "Male: "   << std::count_if(x.begin(), x.end(), std::bind(pred, gender_t::male,   _1)) << ", "
              << "Female: " << std::count_if(x.begin(), x.end(), std::bind(pred, gender_t::female, _1)) << ", "
              << "Other: "  << std::count_if(x.begin(), x.end(), std::bind(pred, gender_t::other,  _1)) << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<osoba> a;

    std::string name;
    char gender;
    while (std::cin >> name >> gender)
        a.push_back({name, to_gender(gender)});

    brosoba(a);
}
```

See it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/68bb506aa9e10a9c)**

For input

```
mike m
thomas m
elayne f
puck o
hector o
troy m
olly f
```

Prints output

```
Male: 3, Female: 2, Other: 2
```

Alternatively, a solution that leaves it open what genders maybe specified:

```
struct osoba
{
    std::string name;
    char gender;
};

void brosoba(std::vector<osoba> const& xs)
{
    std::map<char, size_t> histo;
    for(auto& x : xs)
        histo[x.gender]++;

    for (auto& entry: histo)
        std::cout << entry.first <<  ": " << entry.second << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<osoba> a;

    std::string name;
    char gender;
    while (std::cin >> name >> gender)
        a.push_back({name, gender});

    brosoba(a);
}
```

This now prints (**[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5355d4b1f7f74cd)**):

```
f: 2
m: 3
o: 2
```

Comment: In case you don't mind a lambda or two, here's a more succinct version of the histo function: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7137996/

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would declare function as:

```
void brosoba(struct osoba * x)
```

Also, you call it without passing an argument. You might try:

```
brosoba( a );
```

This will pass pointer to first element of `a` , of type `struct osoba *`. Then, since every element of this array is an *object*, not a pointer, you should read fields with `.` , not `->`.

Furthermore, you are comparing the array of char ( `a[i].pol` ) with a char - single quotes mean character literal, while double quotes mean null terminated character array, so it's another thing to fix.

Comment: that's so ... [tag:c] why don't you suggest C++ idioms for a [tag:c++] question?

Comment: @sehe Well, as the poster stated, it's task from his 'professor'. I assumed he _mistagged_ his question as C++ (_pointers in void function while working with array_ doesn't look much _classy_ to me). If not your edit with those nice C++11 hints I would post updated solution myself :)

Comment: C++ is not just about classes, of course. But yeah. The code wasn't classy in any sense of the word